# Typescript dictionary of functions expects intersection of parameters instead of union

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have the following code:

```js
const fns = {
    foo: (x: string) => x,
    bar: (x: number) => x
}

const caller = (input: { foo: string, bar: number}) => {
    const [k, v] = Object.entries(input)[0]
    return fns[k as keyof typeof fns](v)
}
```

Right now, this fails with the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Typescript seems to correctly infer that `v` is of type `string | number`, but seems to think that the passed in type must be `string & number` for the first parameter.

Is there a way to get Typescript to infer the right types?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZpGBeGBvAUDL8QgFwwAUAHgdAE4CWYA5gJTIB8MxANJtgEYCG5BJBMAFcAtpwCm5BkmbF0AX3TpQkWMG4AbDZORFqAByFQCqHPhgVqNVjB58YwsZPnTmGbDBXQYAbQDWNgBuALq6APKcAFbiwFAAdOJgUFTiEIQGRnQ+AAzBHFjk4lBC5GDwkP4w3BAwfuIAniBwMFD1+uJN5RDBhIF0+TAA9IMeo2PjE1gAegD8CkA)

Comment: What do you expect the type of `fns[someVariable]` to be?